# Mongo: How do I get an element from array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm a new in Mongo. I have a such json structure

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId(
        "aaaaaaa"
    ),
    "university": {
        "short_name": "...",
        "full_name": "...",
        "faculties": [{
            "id": 287,
            "short_name": "...",
            "full_name": "...",
            "departments": [{
                "id": 337,
                "short_name": "...",
                "full_name": "...",
                "teachers": [{
                    "id": 1053,
                    "short_name": "X1",
                    "full_name": "Y1"
                }, {
                    "id": 549,
                    "short_name": "X2",
                    "full_name": "Y2"
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

I want to get the teacher element (`university.faculties.departments.teachers`) by `ID` and `short_name`, but unfortunately retrieves or nothing or entire document. I tried to use `$elemMatch` but it doesn't work with nested objects.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/).

```
db.school.find(
    {
        _id : "document_id", 
        "university.short_name" : "..."
    }, 
    {
        "university.faculties.departments.teachers" : 1
        , _id : 0
    }
)
```

Comment: Since It's not clear in the question, This answer finds document by `_id` and short name of the `university`. If you need to fetch only teachers by teacher's Id and short name, see [Bertrand's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41783507/2965883).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get only the `teacher` object, you can use an aggregation like :

```
db.test.aggregate([{
        // match teacher id to exclude irrelevant documents
        "$match": {
            "university.faculties.departments.teachers.id": 1053
        }
    },
    {
        // unwind faculties array
        $unwind: "$university.faculties"
    }, {
        // unwind departments array
        $unwind: "$university.faculties.departments"
    }, {
        // filter teacher id
        $project: {
            teachers: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$university.faculties.departments.teachers",
                    as: "teachers",
                    cond: { $eq: ["$$teachers.id", 1053] }
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        // unwind teachers array (created with $filter)
        $unwind: "$teachers"
    }, {
        // group by teachers field
        $group: {
            _id: "$teachers"
        }
    }
])
```

which gives :

```
{ "_id" : { "id" : 1053, "short_name" : "X1", "full_name" : "Y1" } }
```